# Twitter card is not being rendered even with meta tags present

Tags: html, twitter, facebook-opengraph, twitter-card

Working on trying to create twitter cards. I have the following meta tags in the header of the page. For some reason when I put the link in my tweet, the twitter card is not being rendered. Any suggestions?

```
<!--- og: tags to create nice facebook & twitter posts for an auction --->
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@herberzt_dev" />
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@herberzt_dev" />
<% if !@item.nil? %>
    <meta property="og:title" content="<%= @item.name %>"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="<%= request.original_url %>"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="<%= @item.photo(:thumbnail) %>"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="<%= @item.description %>"/>
    <meta name="twitter:site" content="@herberzt_dev">
<% elsif !@auction.nil? %>
    <meta property="og:title" content="<%= @auction.name %>"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="<%= request.original_url %>"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="<%= @auction.photo %>"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="<%= @auction.description %>"/>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Should this line;

```
<% elsif !@auction.nil? %>
```

be:

```
<% elseif !@auction.nil? %>
```